# Regex replacing special characters in a string

Tags: regex

I have numerical values that contain special characters and I would like to replace those special characters with "x"

I already tried [^\w*], and it will only work when there is one special character

When there is more than  1234?12?, it won't capture the second special character, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could use. It will replace all none numeric characters. Good luck!

```js
var str = "rt5121212?232?2*dse%e&323"
var pattern = /([^![0-9])/gi;
var sanitized = str.replace(pattern,'');
console.log(sanitized);
```